# Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS File Sharing Permissions

Tags: server, permissions, samba, transmission

Linux beginner here.  I'm trying to make (what I think) is a very simple setup with my server, but I'm finding a ton of conflicting information.  I'm using my server to share folders via samba to two Windows 8.1 machines and various Android devices.  I'm also running Transmission and have a separate folder system set up for that.

For my purposes, I effectively have 4 users. `root userA userB debian-transmission`

I want `userA` and `userB` to have read/write permissions on all current and all created files in multiple directories, including the directories owned and written by `debian-transmission`.  However, when transmission downloads a file, it is the owner and `userA` and `userB` cannot access the files and move them to another folder without SSHing into the server and manually changing the permissions on the files.

My research results so far fall into two camps.  The first is that I should be using a ACL approach, the second is that ACL is overkill and all of this can be done with standard permissions.  I've tried multiple guides for making it work with standard permissions, but have gotten nowhere.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SETGID was the answer I was looking for.  I opted to avoid the ACL approach as most reading I did indicated it was overkill for my purposes.

First step was to go to create a new group to hold my users:

```
sudo groupadd MyNewGroup
```

Then add my users to it:

```
sudo usermod -aG MyNewGroup userA
sudo usermod -aG MyNewGroup userB
sudo usermod -aG MyNewGroup debian-transmission
```

Assign ownership to the folder and all its child folders:

```
sudo chown -R userA:MyNewGroup /mnt/ParentFolder
```

Add permissions as needed to all existing files:

```
chmod -R 770 /mnt/ParentFolder
```

And this was the part eluding me, set the GID so that all new files are owned by the group:

```
chmod g+s /mnt/ParentFolder
```

All new files created in directories set like this will allow anyone in the group to have the permissions you have set.